# How to let vscode show java overloads intellisense like c++

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I use vscode work with C++, I can get the overloads tips.
How can I get similar information when work with Java?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The extension [Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) provides Java Linting, Intellisense, formatting and more..

[image]

Check if you install the right extension, OR you can install [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), which includes popular extensions for Java development.

**[UPDATE]**

About the method `write()`, it has [three overrides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html). Java language server exactly displays three choices for you and provides related method description:

[image]

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. I already can this information like the picture. But I mean when the method have more than one types of arguments。For example, the write() of java.io.FileOutputStream has four kinds of overloads. but I can only see one kind of tipps.
[link](https://overpic.net/viewer.php?file=x56btx5aiwu9mcnjggw3j.png)